# Preg Match GF to pull data from API CALL (Podio CRM)

Tags: regex, crm, podio

I am trying to accomplish pulling all of the data that populates from this API CALL made within my CRM Podio...

The API call response is the following:

```
{
  "status": {
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "code": 0,
    "msg": "SuccessWithResult",
    "total": 1,
    "page": 1,
    "pagesize": 10,
    "transactionID": "ba31a62303e76d49b2063e94e2972bc6"
  },
  "property": [
    {
      "identifier": {
        "Id": 34476108,
        "fips": "48201",
        "apn": "1288930010042",
        "attomId": 34476108
      },
      "lot": {
        "lotnum": "42",
        "lotsize1": 0.2735078,
        "lotsize2": 11914,
        "poolind": "YES"
      },
      "area": {
        "blockNum": "1",
        "loctype": "VIEW - NONE",
        "countrysecsubd": "Harris",
        "countyuse1": "1001 ",
        "muncode": "HA",
        "munname": "HARRIS",
        "subdname": "BLACKHORSE RANCH SOUTH SEC 6",
        "taxcodearea": "40"
        "legal1": "BLACK HORSE RANCE LOT 14 BLOCK 12 USA"
```

etc.

I have tried the following code to pull just the legal description but it returns the entire API response in the comments of my crm. I am trying to get all data points listed individually.

```
preg_match_gf("/legal1\.\:\s\/(.*)/ism",[(Variable) PropertyDetails], 1)
```

Any advise or insight is much appreciated!!

Thank you,

Cody

Comment: Why are you not just using [`json_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) on this?

Comment: You [can see an example over at 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/453TO)

Comment: Because I know very little about coding - appreciate your response. Ill check out your example to see if I can get it to work. Thank you!

Comment: I am using Globiflow within Podio CRM - I'm not sure json decode is a viable solution. @Jaquarh